# d3 transition of areas for shrinking datasets

Tags: d3.js, transition

I'm wondering why the following transition does not work as expected:

in a line chart, users can select different timespans they want the chart to display. If the timespan increases, then the animation is fine: the line moves a bit to the right and the area below that line moves 100% perfect (no gaps or such between line and area).

If on the other hand **the timespan decreases then the area transition displays an ugly behavior:**

**1) initial state**
[image]

**2) change to one week, transition starts**
[image]

**3) transition has a duration of 1 sec**
[image]

**4) end state - no problem here.**
[image]

I'm using basically the same transition functions for the line:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function (d) { return y(d.result2); });
```

and for the area:

```
var area1 = d3.svg.area()
.x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function (d) { return y(d.result2); });
```

I'm not using any explicit enter() or exit() in the area update:

```
// update area1
svg.selectAll(".area1")
.transition()
.duration(1000)
.attr("d", area1(data));
```

I could not figure out how to use enter() or exit() in the case of areas, **maybe an explicit exit().remove() that would instantly remove unneeded datapoints would solve my problem**? But .. how to do that for a line / area??

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Alright, it was no problem of exit().remove() because for a single line, that doesn't make much sense as I see now, too.
What fixed the transition from large to small dataset was cloning the array of data for the full 4 weeks max-timespan, then giving all datapoints that are outside of the currently visible timespan a y-value of 0 and using this array to feed the areas:

```
svg.selectAll(".area1")
    .data([data2]) // contains data for 4 weeks, with 0's on time outside of current span
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", area1);
```

The x-axis is still feed the array with data of only the currently visible timespan, so it adjusts:

```
// array "data" contains only data for the desired time horizon, eg 1 week
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

Comment: You're not actually using any selections, as you're not using `.data()` -- that would be something like `svg.selectAll(".area1").data([data]).transition().attr("d", area1)`. Anyway, the problem is caused by the area being oriented the wrong way round (i.e. flipped along the line). You can try to prevent that by explicitly ordering the data points.

Comment: Hi Lars, found out that reversing the data before updating the areas gives an almost good looking transition-effect in my case. Do you have any link on enter() and exit() pattern for lines/areas with changing dataset-size? I'm doing hard to understand that. e.g. enter().append("path") results in 10 seperate paths added. Got it working with circles, though.

Comment: For areas and lines this usually only makes sense if you have multiple of those -- for a single area/line, your enter/exit/update selection will only contain a single element. Try passing in your data as an array (e.g. `.data([data])`) and it should work.

Comment: Makes sense (enter/exit will contain only a single element). Passing in the data as an array did not change anything, unfortunatly.

Comment: You would have to post a complete example for me to investigate that properly, but I guess it doesn't have anything to do with your original problem.

Comment: Yes, original question was solved .. single area/line => enter/exit selection would only contain a single element. Thanks for your effort, I'll try some more to figure out why the area is drawn so strange when the dataset shrinks.

Comment: I've got it working .. but in an extremly stupid way, I guess. Will edit my question ..

Comment: * Adjusts monocle * hoowhat do we have here

Comment: @peter sir, can you please step out of the vehicle

Comment: @amiawizard, sorry but I don't understand your comment :o/